# return View("myHtmlPage.html") in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Masters,

In my MVC application many pages are static (HTML pages).
I've to create both .cshtml and plain HTML pages.

HTML version is also in use by another module.

When I try with `return View("Mypage.html")` it fails.

Is there any way to consume plain "HTML" pages for my View.

Please help.

Comment: I found something like return new FilePathResult("path_and_file.html", "text/html");

Comment: Are the HTML files publicly accessible?

Comment: No.. it must not.. It should be for internal use only

Comment: Are the HTML files in the `Views` folder?

Comment: No.. it is in root level folder

Comment: Did you try `return View("~/Mypage.html");`?

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the past was to register ".html" pages to be interpreted as dynamic pages, too. (I.e. just like ASPX).

This can be done through your **"web.config**" file:

....
<

```
system.web>
    <compilation ...>
        <buildProviders>
            <add extension=".html" 
                 type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
        </buildProviders>

....and
```

....

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-HTML" path="*.html" 
             verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" 
             resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
```

this works well with IIS 7 and IIS 7.5 (and probably on above versions, too). If you are using IIS 6, you have to do it through the IIS Management Console.

Hope this helps..